# Ruby-Gem failing on nokia n800

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokia

I have a Nokia N800 that I am attempting to install Ruby on.  I installed ruby and rubygems from http://pierre.droids-corp.org/maemo/.  When attempting to do "gem update" or "gem install file.gem" I am getting the following message: "/usr/bin/gem:9:in 'require':no such file to load - - rubygems (LoadError) from /usr/bin/gem:9". Is there a known fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to install RubyGems. Get it from [RubyForge](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=126)  and run (as root, if appropriate and necessary)

```
ruby setup.rb
```